# How to join on a default value from the 2nd table if no match is found?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I'm looking for a way to join 2 tables as follows:

```
T1:           T2:

a    b         c    d    e          
-------        -------------        
1    b1        1    d1   e1         
2    b2        2    d2   e2         
3    b3        ST   d0   e0         


--> join on T1.a = T2.c (if no match found join on T1.c = ST)
a    b    c    d    e
----------------------
1    b1   1    d1   e1
2    b2   2    b2   e2
3    b3   ST   d0   e0         <- No match found so ST values are used.
```

Right now I only found a way when T2.c are integers. I do a conditional join en afterwards i take the max value of c en group by every other column.

Is there any way to do this with string values like in the example in the match column?

Thanks

Comment: Is there exactly one non-numeric value in that second table?

Comment: No there are more. Thi was only the basis of my problem. In reality the join is matched on columns and the 2nd column(attribute) defines wich default value needs to be used in the first columns.
So when the Attribute column is 'at1'. The default values that needs to be used are in the row where t2.c ='St'
When Atrribute column  = 'at2' then the default values that needs to be used are in the row where t2.c ='St2'.
But this isn't really a problem . Together with the answer from @GordonLinoff I've made it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a default.  You can use `left join`:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.c, t2def.c) as c,
       coalesce(t2.d, t2def.d) as d, coalesce(t2.e, t2def.e) as e
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.a = t2.c left join
     t2 t2def
     on t2def.c = 'ST';
```

Or, you can use `apply`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t2
      where t2.c in ('ST', t1.a)
      order by (case when t2.c = 'ST' then 2 else 1 end)
     ) t2;
```